# How to count rows in nested data_frames with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, split-apply-combine

Here's a dumb example dataframe:

```
df <- data_frame(A = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 4)), B = 1:9) %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  nest()
```

which looks like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 2 × 2
      A             data
  <dbl>           <list>
1     1 <tibble [5 × 1]>
2     2 <tibble [4 × 1]>
```

I would like to add a third column called `N` with entries equal to the number of rows in each nested data_frame in `data`. I figured this would work:

```
> df %>% 
+   mutate(N = nrow(data))
Error: Unsupported type NILSXP for column "N"
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Try this: `df$nRow <- sapply(df$data, nrow)` instead. You need this done one cell at a time. Can't do `nrow` on the whole column of data frames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining `dplyr` and `purrr` you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(n = map_dbl(data, nrow))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>       A             data     n
#>   <dbl>           <list> <dbl>
#> 1     1 <tibble [5 × 1]>     5
#> 2     2 <tibble [4 × 1]>     4
```

I like this approach, because you stay within your usual workflow, creating a new column within mutate, but leveraging the `map_*`-family, since you need to operate on a list.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(N = nrow(data))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#Groups: <by row>
#
## A tibble: 2 × 3
#      A             data     N
#  <dbl>           <list> <int>
#1     1 <tibble [5 × 1]>     5
#2     2 <tibble [4 × 1]>     4
```

Comment: Very nice solution within the `dplyr` solution compared to the `apply` family I mentioned above. I like this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(N = nrow(data.frame(data)))
```

> ```
>       A             data     N
>   <dbl>           <list> <int>
> 1     1 <tibble [5 × 1]>     5
> 2     2 <tibble [4 × 1]>     4
> ```